# C++Type inspection

Tags: c++, reflection, rtti

I have a c++ class:

```
Class farm {


...
protected:
vector<ff_node*> workers;
};

//ff_node an abstract method representing a single thread
class ff_node {
protected:
   //svc is the method to encapsulate a sequential function
   void* svc(void *)=0;
```

};

```
Class farm_withMoreWorkers: public farm {
void addWorker(){
  ff_node *newWorker;

  newWorker=new ff_node();// rather than adding ff_node make the instance type as that of type workers since ff_node is abstract
  farm:: workers.push_back(newWorker);
}
};
```

The class ff_node is abstract . In order to add one more worker, I need to create a new instance whose type is the same as the others (all of the workers are of the same type) 
Is there a way to get the specific type of (one of the) workers and create an instance of that type?!

Comment: Please provide more info. It seems that `ff_node` is not an abstract class (since you can `new ff_node();`), but then it makes no sense to have a `vetor<ff_node*>`.

Comment: The specific type of `workers` is `vector<ff_node*>`. What exactly are you hoping to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a pure virtual clone function in the base class and override it in every derived class.

```
class ff_node
{
 public:
 virtual ff_node* clone() = 0;
};

class ff_child : public ff_node
{
 public:
 ff_node* clone() override {new ff_child;}
};
```

Now, given a `ff_node* node`, you can create another instance of the same runtime type by calling `node->clone()`.

Answer (score 0):

You gave very little info, so I'm speculating as to what you actually want. Suppose there is an abstract (pure virtual) class

```
class worker { /* define some useful virtual interface */ };
```

and you want to use several polymorphism to use several differernt workers. Then you best keep them in a `vector` of `unique_ptr`, so that at the end of the `vector`'s scope the workers are automatically `delete`d. You can add a new worker by directly constructing it from arguments provided by the user. Since the type of the new worker may not even be known at the time of definition of the `farm`, this functionality must be provided as `template`. For example

```
class farm
{
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<worker>> workers; //
public:
  // constructs new worker of type Worker with arguments provided
  template<typename Worker, typename... Args>
  void add_worker(Args&&...args)
  { workers.emplace_back(new Worker(std::forward<Args>(args)...)); }
};
```

and use it like this

```
struct builder : public worker
{
  builder(string const&, const widget*, some_type);
  /* ... */
};

farm the_farm;
widget w( /* ... */ );
some_type x;
the_farm.add<builder>("the new builder", &w, x);
```

Note that in the call to `farm::add()` only the first template parameter must be provided, the others will be deduced from the function arguments.